# What is the number 1x 2x 3x that VSCode shows when I'm saving a file and how to disable it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've never noticed this thing before and this is driving me crazy.
I don't know what functionality is this, whether it is an extension or VSCode native.

Whenever I save something, VSCode shows a kind of counter on the right, and this "counter" goes forever (1x, 2x, 3x, 4x...) until I stop saving.

The image shows the counter "3x" on the right
[image: The image shows the counter "3x" on the right]

I don't know what is this and how to disable it, could someone explain what is this for?

Comment: Surely an extension. Did you try uninstalling the ones you have?

Comment: this is the 4th or so question about these Nx numbers, it is an not revealed named extension

Comment: The question was exactly about this, I didn't know if it is about an extension or another thing. But the following answer solved the issue. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Go to VS code setting > click on extension > power mode > change setting of power mode in combo section as per your requirement it will be resolved

If you want to close screen shaking while typing any key disable from shake section
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsFhf.png)

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue and later I found that I have installed an extension called Power Mode which creates the issue. After uninstalling that extension, the issue is resolved.

Try uninstalling this extension:

[image: Refer the image to see the extension]

Comment: You are right, I'd installed this extension "Power Mode". I uninstalled the extension and the issue was solved! Thank you very much for your answer and your time! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Powermode › Combo: Location = OFF : to hide 1x 2x 3x

Powermode › Explosions: Duration = if you reduce its value , flame disappear accordingly

Powermode › Explosions: Size = it will decrease verticle size of flame

Comment: How is this different from the other answers?