vscode save times counter blocked the view

very dummy question, I don't know is it a vscode setting or because of some extensions.
it's kind of annoying for me now

Some extension. Try disabling them one by one.

Most likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/71369306/11613622

yeah，thanks, that's the one
